# Invalid hook call with select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql

Problem is called in ProductSort(), reason is onChange.
I am getting 'invalid hook call' but I have no idea how to rewrite the code to skip this problem.
Maybe you have some ideas?

I will be appreciate, if you will send some links with examples of applications on GraphQL and React.

```
 function ShowCategories(){
    
       const { loading, error, data } = useQuery( gql`
        query{
             categories{ name }
           }
        `);
    
        if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;
    
        if(loading){
          return(<option>Loading...</option>);
        } else{
          return(  data.categories.map( (category, index) => {
            return(<option key={index} value={index}> {category.name} </option>)}) );
        }
    
       }
    
    function ProductSort() {
    
        return(
          <form id="plpChooseCategory">
            <div className="field">
              <select onChange={ (event) => ShowCategories({name: event.target.value})}>
                {ShowCategories()}
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>
        )
```

Comment: If `ShowCategories` is supposed to be a React component then it needs to be rendered as JSX, not invoked like a function. If it is not a React component then you can't use React hooks in it. What is the goal you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @DrewReese I am trying to make an option which will allow user to choose category of something, simply to sort some data. for example in options: Nike, laptops..  so I want to get nike, and export it to other part where i will us it to sort data from 'all ' to category nike.. but i just started with react so i have issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks can only be called from the body of React function components or custom React hooks. The code in your snippets if calling `ShowCategories` as if it were a regular function, which isn't how React components are used.

Move the `useQuery` logic into `ProductSort` and render the data into the options.

```
function ProductSort() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gql`
    query{
      categories{ name }
    }
  `);

  const onChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    // do something with selected value
  };

  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  return (
    <form id="plpChooseCategory">
      <div className="field">
        <select onChange={onChange}>
          {loading
            ? <option disabled value="">Loading...</option>
            : data.categories.map((category, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={index}>
                {category.name}
              </option>
            ))
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```